# Как организовать правку модели с возможностью применить/отменить изменения

Tags: angularjs

Приветствую!

Имеем примерно следующее:

Модель, скажем, товаров:

```
this.trade_model = [
    {
        name: 'name1',
        title: 'title_one',
        cost: 1000,
        ...
    },
    ...
];
```

Полей типа `name`, `title`, `etc..` может быть множество.

По клику показываем `<input ng-model="needed_object.name">`, который правит  `name` объекта нашей модели.

Как дать ввести человеку новое значение, затем после нажатия кнопки "ОК" применить значение к полю модели или же после нажатия кнопки "ОТМЕНА" сбросить введённые значения.

Прошу прощения если не понятно объяснил :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сделать редактирование копии нужного элемента, а не непосредственно элемента массива.

```
this.trade_model = [
    {
        name: 'name1',
        title: 'title_one',
        cost: 1000,
        ...
    },
    ...
];

this.editIs = false;
this.editIndex = -1;
this.editObject = null;

this.edit = function (index) {
    if (!this.trade_model[index]) {
        return;
    }

    this.editIs = true;
    this.editIndex = index;
    this.editObject = angular.copy(this.trade_model[index]);
};

this.editCancel = function () {
    this.editIs = false;
    this.editIndex = -1;
    this.editObject = null;
};

this.editDone = function () {
    this.trade_model[this.editIndex] = angular.copy(this.editObject);

    this.editCancel();
};
```

Либо же наоборот, сохранять оригинал, чтобы если нужно, откатить до него и редактировать напрямую в массиве.

Comment: я извиняюсь за долгую реакцию, но я не совсем понимаю как это реализовать, поэтому и упомянул поле `<input ng-model="needed_object.name">` Не могли бы поподробней рассказать как пользоваться данными функциями?

Comment: Ваш `needed_object` в моём случае, это `this.editObject`. Также у Вас написано `По клику показываем ...`. Т.е. делаем вызов `this.edit(index)`, который создаёт нам объект для редактирования `this.editObject`. После этого мы где-то у Вас нажимаем `Сохранить` и вызываем `this.editDone()`, который заменяет объект в массиве на изменённый, либо вызываем `this.editCancel()`, и отменяем изменения.

Comment: у вас в крайней функции editDone используется index (`this.trade_model[index]`), я так полагаю вы просто упустили его в передаваемой переменной функции?

Comment: @Николай да, вы правы. Только из сохранённой `this.editIndex`. Отредактировал.